# Cannot deploy SCCM 2012 client

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sccm, sccm-2012, sql-server-2014

I'm attempting to get System Center Configuration Manager 2012 up and running for my organization, but my attempts to roll out the client don't appear to be successful within my test group.

My current installation attempt is on a Hyper-V virtual machine. I have both the Configuration Manager instance and it's MS SQL 2014 instance running on the same VM.

This is the first time I've dealt with anything System Center, so I've been following a guide [here](http://prajwaldesai.com/sccm-2012-r2-step-by-step-guide/), Except for the WSUS section (we already have that set up elsewhere). I've been able to successfully install SCCM.

I believe I have all the correct ports open in the firewall (HTTP, HTTPS, File and Printer sharing, etc...). In the SCCM console, I have AD System, Forest, Group and user discovery set up, It has detected all of the separate subnets our equipment are one, I've connected it to our Exchange server and I have a single site set up for our whole company.

Looking in the Assets and Compliance, all of the computers and users in our organization are showing up, but the computers report "No" in the client column.

The account I've specified for all SCCM tasks, including client deployment is in the local "Administrators" group of my test machines. It is also part of our "Domain Admins" group, which has almost completely free reign of all machines.

SCCM is currently set to automatically deploy the client on any and all machine's it finds. Most of those report errors in "ccm.log" except for my test machines with proper tweaks to their firewalls via group policy. The installations appear to kick off in the background properly. On a test machine, I can open task manager a few minutes after manually triggering deployment and find the "ccmsetup.exe" process running.

I've searched arround quite a bit for a solution and made some troubleshooting tweaks I can't remember now to describe here. Any input would be much appreciated. I can provide individual logs or details if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.windows-noob.com/forums/topic/4045-step-by-step-guides-system-center-2012-r2-configuration-manager/

You may need to use the ccmsetup.exe installation properties. Please follow the guide above as well as the ccmsetup.exe properties below to get the agent installed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699356.aspx